# Question about calculation in Schwartz space.

Tags: sobolev-spaces, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

While reading a paper, I experienced that my calculation results kept differing from the author's calculation results.

The authors of the paper seem to believe that the following equation holds:
$$\int_\mathbb{R} xf'(x) \Lambda^{2s}f dx= -\int_\mathbb{R} (\Lambda^s f)^2 dx-\frac{1}{2}\int_\mathbb{R}x[(\Lambda^s f)^2]' dx$$
where $s>3$ is a constant and $\Lambda^s f:=[(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{f}]^{\vee}$  , $\hat{f}(\xi):=\int_\mathbb{R}f(x) e^{-2\pi i\xi x}dx$ (Fourier transform) and $\check{f}(x):=\int_\mathbb{R} f(\xi)e^{2\pi i \xi x}dx$ (Inverse Fourier transform). $f$ is in Schwartz space $S(\mathbb{R})$.

However, my result is different with above. Following all lemmas and theorem are just my opinions.

Lemma 1. $\Lambda^s f=[(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{f}]^{\vee}=[(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\check{f}]^{\wedge}$

proof) This hold because of change of variable $\xi \rightarrow -\xi$.
$$\Lambda^s f(x)=[(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{f}]^{\vee}=\int_\mathbb{R}(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}e^{2\pi i\xi x}\Big{(}\int_\mathbb{R}f(y)e^{-2\pi i\xi y}dy\Big{)}d\xi$$
$$=\int_\mathbb{R}(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}e^{-2\pi i\xi x}\Big{(}\int_\mathbb{R}f(y)e^{2\pi\xi y}dy\Big{)} d\xi=[(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\check{f}]^{\wedge}\blacksquare$$

Lemma 2. $\int_\mathbb{R}\Lambda^sg\Lambda^sfdx=\int_\mathbb{R}g\Lambda^{2s}(f)dx$.

proof) This is results derived from weak Parseval's theorem i.e.
$$\forall f,g\in S(\mathbb{R})\ \ \ \ \int_\mathbb{R}\hat{f}gdx=\int_\mathbb{R}f\hat{g}dx$$
If we use weak Parseval's theorem,
$$\int_\mathbb{R}\Lambda^s{f}\Lambda^s{g}dx=\int_\mathbb{R}[(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{f}]^{\vee}[(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\check{g}]^{\wedge}dx=\int_\mathbb{R}\hat{f}(1+\xi^2)^s\check{g}d\xi=\int_\mathbb{R}[(1+\xi^2)^s\hat{f}]^{\vee}(\check{g})^{\wedge}dx$$
$$=\int_\mathbb{R}g\Lambda^{2s}f dx \blacksquare$$

Lemma 3. $\frac{d}{dx}(\Lambda^sf)(x)=\Lambda^s\Big{(}\frac{df(x)}{dx}\Big{)}$. In other words, Linear operator $\Lambda^s$ and $\frac{d}{dx}$ are commutative.

proof) In this proof, we use well-known facts about Fourier transform
$$2\pi i\xi \hat{f}(\xi)=(\frac{d}{dx}f)^{\wedge}(\xi),\ \ \ \frac{d}{d\xi}\hat{f}(\xi)=(-2\pi i) (xf(x))^\wedge(\xi).$$

If we use above facts,
$$\Lambda^s\Big{(}\frac{df(x)}{dx}\Big{)}=[(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}(f')^\wedge]^{\vee}=2\pi i [(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\xi\hat{f}]^{\vee}$$
Then,
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\Lambda^sf)(x)=\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\mathbb{R}}(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}e^{2\pi i\xi x}\hat{f}(\xi)d\xi=2\pi i [(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\xi\hat{f}]^{\vee}=\Lambda^s\Big{(}\frac{df(x)}{dx}\Big{)}\blacksquare$$

$\bf Theorem$ $\int_\mathbb{R}xf'\Lambda^{2s}fdx=-\frac{1}{2}\int_\mathbb{R}x[(\Lambda^s f)^2]'dx+(s-1)\int_\mathbb{R}(\Lambda^sf)^2dx
-s\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\Lambda^{s-1}f)^2dx$ holds

If we use integration by parts and Lemma 3 and Lemma 2
$$\int_\mathbb{R}xf'(x)\Lambda^{2s} f dx=\Big{[}xf(x)\Lambda^{2s} f\Big{]}_{-\infty}^\infty-\int_\mathbb{R}xf(x)(\Lambda^{2s}f)'dx-\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)\Lambda^{2s}fdx$$
$$=-\int_\mathbb{R}\Lambda^s(xf)\Lambda^s(f')dx-\int_\mathbb{R}(\Lambda^sf)^2dx$$

Meanwhile, if we use $(h')^{\vee}=-2\pi ix\check{h}$
$$x\Lambda^sf=x[(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{f}(\xi)]^{\vee}=\frac{i}{2\pi}[\frac{d}{d\xi}((1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{f})]^{\vee}$$
$$=\frac{i}{2\pi}[s\xi(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s-2}{2}}\hat{f}+(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{f}'(\xi)]^{\vee}$$
$$=\frac{i}{2\pi}[s\xi(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s-2}{2}}\hat{f}]^{\vee}+[(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}(xf)^{\wedge}]^{\vee}$$
$$=\frac{i}{2\pi}[s\xi(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s-2}{2}}\hat{f}]^{\vee}+\Lambda^s(xf)$$
In other words,
$$\Lambda^s(xf)=x\Lambda^sf-\frac{i}{2\pi}[s\xi(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s-2}{2}}\hat{f}]^{\vee}$$
Therefore,
$$-\int_\mathbb{R}\Lambda^s(xf)\Lambda^s(f')dx=-\int_{\mathbb{R}}x\Lambda^sf\Lambda^s(f')dx
+\int_\mathbb{R}\frac{i}{2\pi}[s\xi(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s-2}{2}}\hat{f}]^{\vee}\Lambda^s(f')dx$$
If we focus on the second term,
$$\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}[s\xi(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s-2}{2}}\hat{f}]^{\vee}\Lambda^s(f')dx
=\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}[s\xi(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s-2}{2}}\hat{f}]^{\vee}[(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}(f')^{\vee}]^{\wedge}dx$$
If we use weak Parseval theorem and $(h')^{\vee}=-2\pi ix\check{h}$,
$$=\int_\mathbb{R}s\xi^2(1+\xi^2)^{s-1}\hat{f}\check{f}d\xi
=\int_\mathbb{R}s(1+\xi^2)^s\hat{f}\check{f}d\xi-\int_\mathbb{R}s(1+\xi^2)^{s-1}\hat{f}\check{f}d\xi$$
$$=\int_{\mathbb{R}}s(\Lambda^sf)^2dx-\int_{\mathbb{R}}s(\Lambda^{s-1}f)^2dx$$

Therefore,
$$\int_\mathbb{R}xf'(x)\Lambda^{2s}fdx=-\int_\mathbb{R}(\Lambda^sf)^2dx-\int_\mathbb{R}x\Lambda^sf\Lambda^s{f'}dx+
\frac{i}{2\pi}\int_\mathbb{R}[s\xi(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s-2}{2}}\hat{f}]^{\vee}\Lambda^s(f')dx$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2}\int_\mathbb{R}x[(\Lambda^s f)^2]'dx+(s-1)\int_\mathbb{R}(\Lambda^sf)^2dx
-s\int_{\mathbb{R}}(\Lambda^{s-1}f)^2dx \blacksquare$$

I wonder if the calculations of the paper authors are correct or if my calculations are correct. If anyone has any ideas for the calculations, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A significant, thoughtful, and possibly non-gpt question. Which part of your question is most pressing?

Comment: The paper author's result and my calculation result are different.  I wonder if my calculations are correct.  Otherwise, I wonder if there is a way to get the author's result.

Comment: Yo wrote $\Lambda^s f:=[(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{1}{2}}\hat{f}]^{\vee}$; did you intend to write it as $\Lambda^s f:=[(1+\xi^2)^{\frac{s}{2}}\hat{f}]^{\vee}$? (note the $s$ in the exponent)

Comment: Yes, that part was my typo.